# Why does <p id="map"> come up on a new line?

Tags: html

I would to know why the 'map' comes up on a new line.

```
We are playing on <p id="map">
```

The reason I have `<p>` is because it prints as text otherwise but having `<p>` makes it a paragraph, how to I fix it?

Comment: Consider using `span` instead of `p`.

Comment: `<p>` is a paragraph tag and is block level. You could use `<span>`, an inline element. Just to clarify, what do you mean by "it prints as text otherwise"?

Comment: Refer to [these MDN docs on block-level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements)

Comment: ... as well as [these from the W3C which are a little denser than MDN's](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-boxes)

Comment: Do you know what a paragraph actually *is*? You should start by figuring that out first, because a new line is entirely appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

This is because the tag `p` works in the block element. This means, in simple terms, that it uses all width available.

The suggested `span` tag works because it is a inline element, which means that it will only take as much width as necessary.

When you have two or more inline elements, they are kept on the same line, but a block element always span in a new line and nothing can be at their right hand side.

Comment: Also tags need to closed

Comment: @YuriyGalanter `<p>` tags actually don't need a closing tag in HTML. This: `<p>Paragraph 1 <p> Paragraph 2` should be rendered as two sibling paragraphs, not one nested inside another.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter is correct, tags needs to be closed. I'm assuming that the OP gave us a partial HTML document, or else his HTML is not valid.

Answer (score 2):

The `<p>` tag is a paragraph marker, which will be handled by a new line. Not knowing your context, I would agree with Zneak and say you should probably use a `<span>` tag instead.

Answer (score 2):

By default, the `p` element is displayed as a block (`display: block'), which means that there are line breaks before and after the element. Moreover, it has top and bottom margin, corresponding to empty lines, by default. You can override these in CSS.

But it’s a mystery why you would use a `p` element or what you should use instead. The code sample shows nothing after the `<p>` tag, so we cannot know what the element contains. It hardly makes sense to start a paragraph in the middle of a sentence. And by definition, `<p>` element *is* a paragraph.